# Powershell cannot pass in command line string parameter

Tags: powershell

\I have tried everything I can find on the web but I just can't make this work.... Really frustrating. All I want to do is to pass in a file name in the command line to my Powershell script test.ps1.

```
param([String]$input=$args[0])
$inputpath = 'C:\work\'
$inputfile = $($inputpath + $input+".txt")
```

I run the script like:

> > > powershell .\test.ps1 "input"

However, the in the error message I print out, I keep getting "cannot find c:\work\.txt". Apparently my command line parameter isn't in there correctly. Can someone please help?

Comment: shouldn't the error be `can't find c:\work\.txt`? if $input isn't defined in there, powershell wouldn't magically strip off the trailing backslash in $inputpath.

Comment: You're right. just edited. I didn't know I needed to put "\\" for the "\" to show up in stackoverflow.

Comment: So what does $args contain? Dump it, I'd say...

Comment: It works when I hard code the file name in the script. But I want to learn how to pass in the file name in command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change `$Input` into some other name. Because `$Input` is used for Pipeline variable.

See for example:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/12/31/write-powershell-functions-that-accept-pipelined-input.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply use this for building the path:

```
$inputpath = 'C:\work\'
$inputfile = Join-Path $inputpath ($args[0] + ".txt")
```